# Symfony: how to customize output of available commands?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7, symfony-console

We are building a console application using **symfony/console** (great library by the way). The available commands show up as such:

```
Available commands:
  check-deps     Get a report of resolved and missing (if any) dependencies.
  gen-docs       Rebuild the API / code documentation
  help           Displays help for a command
  list           Lists commands
  restart        Restart the Nginx and PHP-FPM processes.
  show-changes   Show all local changes to the source code since the last push.
  test           Run the unit tests
  test-coverage  Run the unit tests and include a coverage report.
```

The name of the command shows up in **green** and the description shows up in white.

Currently, **Available commands** is the only *section*. Is there a simple way using OOP to create multiple *sections* for commands?

Alternatively, is there a way to change the **green** color for the command label?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new section by using colon notation.

```
$this
        ->setName('newSection:greet') //<--- This line does the trick
        ->setDescription('Greet someone')
        ->addArgument(
            'name',
            InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
            'Who do you want to greet?'
        )
        ->addOption(
           'yell',
           null,
           InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
           'If set, the task will yell in uppercase letters'
        );
```

However in that case you need to run your command with new section name added as namespace,
`> php app.php newSection:greet Avindra`.

If you name your section with a whitespace like "New Section" you need to call your command like,
`> php app.php "New Section:greet" Avindra`.

And this is how you can change the color of `info` annotation of the application itself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Command\GreetCommand;
use Command\HelloCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyle;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new GreetCommand());
$application->add(new HelloCommand());

//Create a new OutputFormatter
$formatter = new OutputFormatter();
//Change info annotation color by blue
$formatter->setStyle('info', new OutputFormatterStyle('blue'));
//Construct output interface with new formatter
$output = new ConsoleOutput(OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_NORMAL, null, $formatter);

//Run your application with your new output interface
$application->run(null, $output);
```

You can check the related source code for more options here;
https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/5f241906889f0a3e7b1854b42e7c92a0ea8516ce/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php#L51

https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/b6b351d326e2fb2fe673a808630f938c2881a473/Formatter/OutputFormatterStyle.php#L21

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely gives me a place to start. This line of code seems interesting https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/b6b351d326e2fb2fe673a808630f938c2881a473/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php#L210 There doesn't seem to be a really clean way to hook into it, but it seems that I can modify the color of the command depending on it's type, at least.

Comment: I think you are right about Textdescriptor. It's initiated here https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/b6b351d326e2fb2fe673a808630f938c2881a473/Helper/DescriptorHelper.php#L39 and it seems like it's registered by default. Maybe you can try to register your own Descriptor class for the applications  HelperSet.